# Use verbatim inside \texttt

Tags: verbatim, typewriter

Why can't I use `\begin{verbatim}` inside `\texttt`?

```
\texttt{ \small \begin{verbatim} 
iab <key> <expansion>
<key> is the string which should be expanded to <expansion>
\end{verbatim}}
```

This throws an error.

I can do this without any problem,

```
{\tt \small \begin{verbatim} 
iab <key> <expansion>
<key> is the string which should be expanded to <expansion>
\end{verbatim}}
```

but I read, `\tt` is gone now.

Comment: Why would you, `verbatim` prints the contents in typewriter text anyways.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. So that the text shows as a separate block of code.

Comment: Yes, that's what the `verbatim` environment does, nothing to with `\texttt`. If you remove `\tt` or `\texttt` and recompile, does that give you what you want?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, it works. Then, what is `\tt` and `\small` doing there? Oops, I know I should know, but I can't remember.

Comment: `\small` reduces the font size a little, but the use of `\tt` is just a misunderstanding I guess, it is unnecessary.

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin. Additionally, the raw TeX macro `\tt` shouldn't be used. Consider using `\ttfamily` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Environment `verbatim` and macro `\verb` change the catcodes. The catcodes are used, when TeX generates tokens from the input characters. If the tokenization is already done, the catcode changes do not have an effect. This happens if the verbatim stuff is put in the argument of another macro (here: `\texttt`). This can be avoided by using a group with `\ttfamily` instead of `\texttt`:

```
{% start group
\par % see below
\ttfamily\small % font changes
text bla bla ...
\begin{verbatim}
verbatim text ...
\end{verbatim}
text bla bla ...
\par % see below
}% end group
```

`\small` also changes the line spacing. TeX uses the values for the line spacing at the end of a paragraph, when it generates lines from the paragraph. Therefore I have 
explicitly added `\par` at the begin and end of the group.